# Designing a Sharepoint Workflow Distribution list filtered on column values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on putting together a Sharepoint site to report issues with a new software that is being implemented by my company.  I already have a workflow that automatically sends an email to specific accounts whenever a new issue is added to the site.  However, I need to make it so that the list is filtered and only sends to certain email accounts depending upon values in certain categories.  For example, if certain values are selected in the column "Issues" it will send out notifications to specific people.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoint Designer. In it, you can do all of the logic you describe. You have the ability to check the value of a column (whenever its value is changed/set by someone, for example), and depending on that value send an email to whomever you like. You can also dynamically send emails based on a Person column, so if you want to send an email to whoever created the list item, for example, you would just indicate the "Created By" column as the email recipient.